# Error handling using volley in android

Tags: android, json, error-handling, android-volley

I want to print my Error from `onErrorResponse` using `volley` in android, i want to print them `separately` in different `textview`.

my error from `onErrorResponse`

```
{
    "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
    "error": {

      "username": [
            "The username has already been taken."
        ],
        "email": [
            "The email has already been taken."
        ]
    },
    "status_code": 422
}
```

so i want to print them separately, 
i mean `The username has already been taken.` in one `textview` and `The email has already been taken.` in 2nd `textview`. thank

My Code:

```
public void postData(JSONObject jsonObject) {       
    String url = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/api/v1/auth/register";
    String REQUEST_TAG = "volley_key";      
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, jsonObject,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    try {
                        verifyResponse(response);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {            
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            if (networkResponse != null && networkResponse.data != null) {
                String errorStr = new String(networkResponse.data);                  
                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(errorStr);
                    JSONObject objError = jObj.getJSONObject("error");
                    JSONArray emailArray = objError.getJSONArray("email");
                    if (emailArray != null) {
                        String emailMessage = String.valueOf(emailArray.get(0));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), emailMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                    JSONArray usernameArray = objError.getJSONArray("username");
                    if (usernameArray != null) {
                        String usernameMessage = String.valueOf(emailArray.get(0));
                        Toast.makeText(getApplication(), usernameMessage, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }){
        @Override
        protected VolleyError parseNetworkError(VolleyError volleyError) {

            if (volleyError.networkResponse != null && volleyError.networkResponse.data != null) {
                VolleyError error = new VolleyError(new String(volleyError.networkResponse.data));
                volleyError = error;
            }
            return volleyError;
        }
    };      VolleySingleton.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectReq, REQUEST_TAG);
}
```

Comment: Okay... Parse your json and set up the TextView... What's the problem?

Comment: I'm not answering the question, but `The name field is required.` Probably this should be done by client side. `The email has already been taken.` this is fine.

Comment: @Wizard, yes Ok, I want to print "The username has already been taken", The email has already been taken. thank

Comment: @cricket_007 i know how parse josn in onResponse. but how parse for error?

Comment: It's the exact same idea. Please show what you've tried

Answer (score 1):

Add there ErrorModel.class and Error class into java folder.

```
package co.exmaple;

import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class ErrorModel {

    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    private String message;
    @SerializedName("error")
    @Expose
    private Error error;
    @SerializedName("status_code")
    @Expose
    private Integer statusCode;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public Error getError() {
        return error;
    }

    public void setError(Error error) {
        this.error = error;
    }

    public Integer getStatusCode() {
        return statusCode;
    }

    public void setStatusCode(Integer statusCode) {
        this.statusCode = statusCode;
    }

}
```

Erro.class

```
package co.exmaple;

import java.util.List;
import com.google.gson.annotations.Expose;
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName;

public class Error {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private List<String> name = null;
    @SerializedName("username")
    @Expose
    private List<String> username = null;
    @SerializedName("email")
    @Expose
    private List<String> email = null;

    public List<String> getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(List<String> name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public List<String> getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(List<String> username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public List<String> getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(List<String> email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

}
```

Then in StringError Request set Error text into texView.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {



            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
 GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
                Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();
                ErrorModel error = gson.fromJson(response,ErrorModel.class);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(new ErrorAdapter(ErrorActivity.this,error.getError));
            }
        });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Make RecyclerView adapter to set Error text to TextView

Answer (score 0):

you can check for the keys inside error object and simply can check if the key exists then show the error for particular Textview.
here is the example.I am taking a case where you are using JsonObject class of volley i.e, the response is in JsonObject.

```
JsonObject obj=response.getAsJsonObject("error");
if(obj.has("name")){
    nameTextView.setText(obj.getAsJsonArray("name").get(0)+"");
}
if(obj.has("username")){
    usernameTextView.setText(obj.getAsJsonArray("username").get(0)+"");
}
if(obj.has("email")){
    emailTextView.setText(obj.getAsJsonArray("email").get(0)+"");
}
```

Comment: your code is having many syntax error (closing brackets , missing double quotes) correct it

Comment: @Chandan Bhandari bro plz correct it, its not working.